# Why does VS studio give me an error when I try to import a function, class, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, import, package

The problem is that, when I try to import a certain class from a .py archive that is in the same package it gives me an error. I have tried using from .something import function, from something import function and both ways end in error.

Answer (score -1):

So your question is kinda vague but ive had a similar issue from what I understand in sublime text

to solve this make sure you have the correct python interpreter on visual studio